# Navigation on Windows Phone with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms to write a cross platform app.

To change between Pages I am using `Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());`. This works fine when there is a `NavigationPage`.

Now I want to get rid of the `NavigationPage` on Windows Phone 8.1, because it is destroying my layout.

The [Xamarin.Forms guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/) note, that you do not need a `NavigationPage` on Windows Phone.

> Also note that the Windows Phone platform provides navigation
>   natively. Therefore, you do not need to use a NavigationPage object to
>   get navigation on that platform.

Bu when I do not use a NavigationPage, an Exception will be thrown.

[image]

So what can I do to use Navigation without `NavigationPage` on Windows Phone?

Comment: You can use `PushModalAsync` if it is disturbing your layout. I don't why such a statement in Xamarin site, because all navigations are handled by adding a navigation page.

Comment: Yep, PushModelAsync is working fine. Post it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PushModalAsync if it is disturbing your layout. I don't why such a statement in Xamarin site, because all navigations are handled by adding a navigation page.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushModalAsync/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/